# JavaScript Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one link

```
<a ng-click="logout()">
```

I want to change the above link to below code

```
<a ng-click="logout()" onclick="setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'https://demo.test.ca/log'; }, 3000);">
```

I am using third party solution, In this you can change the code directly without modifying the actual code.

But the problem is that when I write policy for changing the code. When this application is loaded it gives me the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

So please help me to fix this.

Comment: can you show the logout() function !?

Comment: Why there are `ng-click` and `onclick` on the same element.

Comment: The console should tell you exactly which line in code is causing the problem, so why don't you just check it? Your `onclick` is ok, so the error is propably from `ng-click` function.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close `<a>` tag

```
<a ng-click="logout()" onclick="setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'https://demo.test.ca/log'; }, 3000);">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a ng-click="logout()" type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</a>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          window.location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com/")
        }, 3000);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should work,

Can you try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a ng-click="logout()" type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</a>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          window.location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com/")
        }, 3000);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angularjs and ng-click then do it properly and remove that onclick and assign function to $scope in your controller/directive/component so your template would look like:

```
<a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
```

and in your controller/directive/component in logout function:

```
$scope.logout = function () {
  // logout code .... 
  $timeout(()=> {$window.location = 'https://demo.test.ca/log'; }, 3000);
}
```

Also make sure you inject $window and $timeout, if you don't already have it you will need to add it.